# Spark state stream write to cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using pyspark streaming to perform a stateful transformation. The state contains the final data and I would like to save the state to cassandra. Here is my code:

```
# gets new stream of data
new_stream = get_kafka_stream()

# transformations happens here
transformed_stream = transform_stream(new_stream)

# I then update the state in memory
state_stream = transformed_stream.updateStateByKey(update_func)

# save the state to cassandra
load_state_stream(state_stream)
```

Here is the function that tries to load the stream to cassandra:

```
def load_state_stream(stream):
     stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: save(rdd))

     def save(rdd):
            if not rdd.isEmpty():
               df = rdd.toDF() 
              df.write
              .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
             .options(table="flat_table", keyspace="etl")\
              .mode("append")
```

Here are the logs from cassandra:

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-05-04 08:42:01,106 AuthCache.java:172 - (Re)initializing PermissionsCache (validity period/update interval/max entries) (2000/2000/1000)

INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-05-04 08:42:30,669 AuthCache.java:172 - (Re)initializing RolesCache (validity period/update interval/max entries) (2000/2000/1000)
```

Here are the logs from Spark:

```
 2018-05-07 03:02:40 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 21 in stage 15803.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 20.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89026, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 11.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89017, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89006, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 2.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89008, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 7.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89013, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 22.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89028, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 16.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89022, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 18.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89024, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 5.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89011, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 1.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89007, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 23.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89029, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 15.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89021, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 17.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89023, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 9.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89015, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 3.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89009, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 19.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89025, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 4.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89010, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 6.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89012, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 14.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89020, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 12.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89018, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 13.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89019, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 8.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89014, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 10.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89016, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-05-07 03:02:40 ERROR JobScheduler:91 - Error running job streaming job 1525662160000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 65, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 159, in <lambda>
    func = lambda t, rdd: old_func(rdd)
  File "<ipython-input-10-690701637381>", line 3, in <lambda>
    uncouple_stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: stream_to_cassandra(rdd))
  File "<ipython-input-10-690701637381>", line 10, in stream_to_cassandra
    temp_flatobs.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")            .options(table="flat_obs", keyspace="etl")            .mode("append")            .save()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 701, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o547939.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 21 in stage 15803.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 21.0 in stage 15803.0 (TID 89027, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:903)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This method works but after sometime I get a Socket closed exception from spark. What could I be doing wrong.

Comment: please post error message... Do you see any error on Cassandra site?

Comment: hi @AlexOtt, I have added the cassandra logs in the question.

Comment: that's not the actual error... Cassandra logs looks ok

Comment: I added the spark logs as well.

Comment: Is it advisable to save a stream returned by a stateful operation to cassandra?

Comment: With `foreachRDD` it should work, if I remember correctly...

Unfortunately it's unclear from Spark logs what causes this problem - Cassandra, or not.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I was able to go deeper and discovered this is what happens before the socket closed exception occurs, the executor starts losing tasks, as seen in the edit, then the socket exception follows. Could this be a memory issue? the executor is running out of memory?